# Возможно ли реализовать наследование двух SomeExeption1\2 классов от MyExeption класса?

Tags: c#

Создал два класса:

1. SomeExeption1
2. SomeExeption2

которые наследуют класс MyExeption.

Можно ли реализовать программу в таком ключе:

```
public class MyExeption : Exception
    {
        public MyException(string message) : base(message)
        { }
    }
```

```
class SomeException1\2 : MyException
    {
        public SomeException1\2(string message) : base(message)
        { }
    }
```

Если нет, не могли бы подксазать, как это реализовать, важно чтобы SomeException1\2 были наследниками MyException.

Comment: можно и ты это практически сделал

Comment: а чего тут не хватает?

Comment: Если компилируется, то всего хватает.

Comment: Кек в том, что я не могу вызвать ""throw new SomeException1\2" MVS в списке выпадающем их не видит, только "MyException"

Comment: `class SomeException1\2 : MyException` => `public class SomeException1\2 : MyException`

Comment: И раньше были публичными, всяко нет(
Спасибо за помощь, теперь хоть знаю, что должно хотя бы правильно работать.

Comment: Решил проблему, директива была не доступна, прописал юсинг все сработало. Т_Т

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class MyException : Exception
{
    public MyException(string message) : base(message) { }
}
class SomeExceptionFirst : MyException
{
    public SomeExceptionFirst(string message) : base(message) { }
}
class SomeExceptionSecond : MyException
{
    public SomeExceptionSecond(string message) : base(message) { }
}

throw new SomeExceptionFirst("first"); //Submission#0+SomeExceptionFirst: first
throw new SomeExceptionSecond("second"); //Submission#1+SomeExceptionSecond: second
```